# Sorted view of a List

Tags: java, list, sorting

is it somehow possible to get a sorted `List` view of a `List` with the elements from the original List, modify the elements, for example set a property, but the original List should reflect the changes?

Background is I'm sorting two Lists, then for each equal element I'm setting a property (basically it's the intersection) but finally I need the unsorted List with the modified elements.

kind regards,
Johannes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest thing to do is add the elements to a new list, sort that list, and when you modify the elements, the original elements will still be modified...

```
List<?> origA;
List<?> origB;

List<?> newA = new ArrayList<?>(origA);
List<?> newB = new ArrayList<?>(origB);

Collections.sort(newA);
Collections.sort(newB);

// do mods
```

Comment: Yes, obviously that's right... my brain must have been off for a short time because it's late or something like that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If the `List` holds references to objects (not primitive data types), then just copy the list, sort it and modify the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a list? If you keep your elements in a `TreeSet`, they will always be sorted as you iterate through them, even after you add/remove the elements. Remember though that modifying an element already in the `TreeSet` may break the sort order. You can remove and add the element to the `TreeSet` to get around that.

If you have to use a list, you can use `Collections.sort(List list)` after adding or modifying an element. Of course, if you have to call it often, there will be a performance hit. If performance is a concern, you can just insert the new element (or move the modified one) to maintain the sorted order, which will be cheaper than sorting it: O(n) vs O(n*log(n))